# Populate Elementor Form based on first selection

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, forms

for better understanding, check this elementor tutorial https://youtu.be/wYv0tMFDFG0?si=cg2nQE6a5zl0FdHp&t=610

starting with 10:10 min, is what I need.

Instead of Options 1, 2, 3, etc, I have Countries.
When a user select a country (France, UK, Germany) from the list, on the second form will populate Cities from that country (Paris, London, Berlin) which can be selected.

Thanks in advance.